# Why reaching expert level is hard?

Tags: learning, theory, rating, carlsen

I was looking at the rating chart of Magnus Carlsen here's what I found:

He learned chess at age of five(1995),
On April 2001 his rating was 2064.Which means it took the best player in the world 6 years to reach 2000.But after that he quickly reached the GM title.

I researched a bit and found out that till 2000ELO its more or less all about tactics ,after that its all about Openings and Positional play,Strategy,etc.So my question his why its so hard to reach 2000elo.Does it takes the brain a looooong freaking time to get a good grasp and master
the tactics?

Comment: Chess is just a weird activity in that a person is much more limited by whatever "natural talent" they have to begin with. A player could have a 150 IQ with a PhD in pure math, yet may never make it past 2000-2200 even if they worked full time on chess for the rest of their life. Meanwhile, Magnus gets there as a child in a few years, likely studying somewhere around 4-5 hours per day. It's pretty rare to find this in other non-physical activities, at least to the degree that it is the case in chess.